# Django admin change form widget from integer dropdown to checkbox

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I have the following model with a positive small integer field for different status:

```
class Shops(models.Model):

   STATUS_CHOICES = [
          (0, 'Inactive'),
          (1, 'Active'),
          (2, 'Closed'),
          (3, 'Transferred'),
      ]
  status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Status", choices=STATUS_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
```

With this on the admin site status widget will be generated as select box

But i want it to be a checkbox with the checkbox value be 0 and 1 following STATUS_CHOICE, and i already handle the list page to filter by status = 0 or 1 only

On the admin page status would be like so:

[image]

I tried to override the admin change form like so:

```
#Form 

class ShopsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    status = forms.CheckboxInput()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ShopsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['status'] = False
        if self.instance:
            if self.instance.status is not None:
                try:
                    self.initial['status'] = False
                    if self.instance.status == 1:
                        self.initial['status'] = True
                except:
                    pass

        self.fields['status'].label = "Active"

    def clean_status(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['status'] is not None:
            data = self.cleaned_data['status']
        else:
            data = None

        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Shops
        exclude = ['status']

#ModelAdmin

class ShopsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = 50

    form = ShopsForm

    list_display = (
        ...
        'status'
    )

    list_display_links = (
        ...
        'status'
    )

    fields = (
        ...
        'status',
    )

    readonly_fields = (
        'id',
    )


    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.status = 0
        if form.cleaned_data['status'] == True:
            obj.status = 1
        obj.save()
        return super(ShopsAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    pass

admin.site.register(Shops, ShopsAdmin)
```

But i'm getting the following error when go to a change form:

```
File "/app/backend/admin.py", line 2388, in __init__
web_1         |     self.fields['status'].label = "Active"
web_1         | KeyError: 'status'
```

I already set up a custom status field in form and i'm confused , hope someone can help me

**EDIT:**

i changed `status = forms.CheckboxInput()` to `status = forms.IntegerField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput)` and now the checkbox display based on the field

But when i try untick and save it return validation error and won't let me change

> Enter a whole number.

Comment: Do not need exclude = ['status']

Comment: the form has a status field with label = active, but its a dropdown instead of a check box @Blackdoor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem, i'm supposed to use forms.BooleanField() not forms.CheckboxInput()

I changed my form to the following:

```
class ShopsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    active = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StakingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['active'] = False
        if self.instance:
            if self.instance.status is not None:
                try:
                    self.initial['active'] = False
                    if self.instance.status == 1:
                        self.initial['active'] = True
                except:
                    pass

        self.fields['active'].label = "Active"

    def clean_active(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['active'] is not None:
            data = self.cleaned_data['active']
        else:
            data = None

        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Shops
        exclude = []
```

in admin i remove `status` from fields tuple

```
fields = (
        ....
        'active',
        #remove 'status'
    )

#and add override save so checkbox value save into status integer column

ef save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
   obj.status = 0
   if form.cleaned_data['active'] == True:
      obj.status = 1
   obj.save()
   return super(ShopsAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Now i have a checkbox that use IntegerField() choice value of 1 and 2 :)